# Performance of Image loading

Tags: c#, image, stream

I've been experimenting for a few hours with various ways to load an image from file. Please have a look at these two methods:

```
    public Image SlowLoad(string path)
    {
        return Image.FromFile(path);
    }

    public Image FastLoad(string path)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path)))
            return Image.FromStream(ms);  
    }
```

The second method is like 2 times faster. What am I missing here? Why is it so? I can't believe that .NET developers couldn't implement Image.FromFile faster simply using the method I wrote. So => I am wrong somewhere. Please tell me where. Why is the second method almost 2 times faster? Is my code fully correct? (thread-safe, etc.). Maybe Image.FromFile is more secure?

Comment: Are you just measuring the time taken to call your method? It may well be that `Image.FromFile` does a bunch of parsing etc that `Image.FromStream` defers. I don't know, but I'm speculating - can you see this having an impact in a real UI, e.g. that displays the images?

Comment: Just a fyi: [reference.microsoft.com](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Image.cs,f7cc7221ba00597a)

Comment: Your second method requires that the entire file be loaded into memory before being read, which the first method (perhaps) does not.  Maybe Image.FromFile() is optimized for a low memory footprint, such that it only loads a small buffer at a time from the file.

Comment: @Jon Skeet I am measuring the time needed to load and store all the images in a gallery. With `Image.FromFile` it takes about 3.5s, while with `Image.FromStream` it just takes 1.7s. This is the startup time.

Comment: `public Image SuperFastLoad(string path)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path)))
            return Image.FromStream(ms, false, false);  
    }`

Comment: I don't know why, but when I use your SuperFastLoad, the program crashes with some internal GDI+ error. Why is it so?

Comment: IMHO `Image.FromFile` could be randomly accessing offsets which are not contiguous within the file, presuming your image's format is one that makes it possible for such jumps to occur. So in the case of `Image.FromFile` the architects of the .NET BCL had to compromise between memory consumption and time and they chose less memory consumption but slower loads. If this is true, then `Image.FromFile` is affected by hdd jump speeds which is not what is happening when you read the whole file in memory and then let the algorithms behind `Image.FromStream` to do the jumps, which now occur in RAM

Comment: @Randolph - Not sure why it doesnt work, the following works in LINQPad:  `void Main()
{
   ImageLoader l = new ImageLoader();
   System.Drawing.Image t = l.SuperFastLoad(@"test.bmp");
   Console.WriteLine(t.Size.ToString());
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class ImageLoader
{
   public System.Drawing.Image SuperFastLoad(string path)
   {
      using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path)))
      {
         return System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms, false, false);
      }
   }
}`

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK:
First of all Image.FromFile wraps GDI+ GdipLoadImageFromFile* functions, ones has a strange life. GDI+ image **holds and can use source** (file or stream) during whole lifetime, some details about it http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/814675. So, here is some possible "multiple file io" vs "multiple stream io".
Also there is some interesting comment in MS Reference Source System.Drawing.Image:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Image.cs,181

```
class Image {
    ............
    public static Image FromFile(String filename,
                                     bool useEmbeddedColorManagement) 
    {
        ............    
        //GDI+ will read this file multiple times. 
        ............
    }
}
```