# Which line of code is still using the file and not releasing it?

Tags: c#, excel

I am using this code to create an Excel file and populate it with data:

```
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
{
    ExcelWorksheet ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Deltas");
    ExcelWorksheet ws2 = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Images");
    ExcelWorksheet ws3 = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Data Points");

    GenerateDataSheet(ws, true);
    GenerateDataSheet(ws3, false);

    // populate second worksheet with images
    var imagesLocations = SelectedSession.GetTests().Where(t => t.IsReference).Select(t => t.Location).OrderBy(t => t.DateCreated).ThenBy(t => t.Name).ToList();
    ws2.Column(2).Width = 58;

    for (int i = 0; i < imagesLocations.Count; i++)
    {
        ws2.Row(i + 1).Height = 305;

        ws2.Cells[i + 1, 1].Value = imagesLocations[i].Name;
        ws2.Cells[i + 1, 1].Style.VerticalAlignment = ExcelVerticalAlignment.Top;
        ws2.Cells[i + 1, 1].Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Right;

        var imagePath = imagesLocations[i].Tests.FirstOrDefault(t => t.IsReference).ImagePath;
        if (File.Exists(imagePath))
        {
            var ImageToPutInReport = Image.FromFile(imagePath);
            var image = ws2.Drawings.AddPicture(imagesLocations[i].Name, ImageToPutInReport);
            image.SetSize(375, 375);
            image.SetPosition(i, 0, 1, 0);
        }
    }

    package.SaveAs(fileInfo);
}
```

After it finishes, I call a function to delete the Images Folder. The "delete()" function pops an error:

> image is still in use

When I comment the above code the error does not occur. Currently I am using this hack to fix my problem:

```
public static void DeleteSessionFolder(string session)
{
    try
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(baseSessionPath + session))
            Directory.Delete(baseSessionPath + session, true); // error pops here

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        DeleteSessionFolder(session); // call it again
    }
}
```

So I am giving a chance to keep trying again and again. But this is taking like 15 seconds till "that thing" releases the images and the application is able to delete the folder, while the whole application is frozen. **Which line of code is keeping a hold of the images(an image)?**

Comment: I don't know c# but did you close the image?

Comment: Try calling `image.Dispose()` after saving. This will release any resources used by the Image.

Comment: @findwindow You got it first so thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using `Image.FromFile` to get the image you should use a stream to read in a copy of the image and then operate using this copy. The issue with `Image.FromFile` is that it opens your image file by reference so that no other operation can write to it until your application stops using it. It is basically a stream that never closes until it is **completely** out of scope or you manually `.Dispose()` of the image object.

So, change this line:

```
var ImageToPutInReport = Image.FromFile(imagePath);
```

To this line:

```
Image ImageToPutInReport;
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(imagePath))
{
    ImageToPutInReport = Image.FromStream(stream);
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you :)

Comment: Q: which is faster, to dispose or to set a stream? I assume to dispose?

Comment: @FirstStep Here is a question addressing just that. It is not incredibly descriptive but the answer provides some reference links to sites like msdn: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28887314/performance-of-image-loading

Answer (score 1):

From [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5(v=vs.110).aspx) link  on `Image.FromFile(string filename)` it says `The file remains locked until the Image is disposed.` and you don't dipose the image anywhere.

That's what's causing your issue.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
var ImageToPutInReport = Image.FromFile(imagePath);
```

Will keep your image opened and locked until you dispose it (which, since you are not doing explicitly, won't happen till the garbage collector decides to: those should be those 15 seconds you are observing when retrying)... so I'd change that block to:

```
using(var ImageToPutInReport = Image.FromFile(imagePath))
{
  var image = ws2.Drawings.AddPicture(imagesLocations[i].Name, ImageToPutInReport);
  image.SetSize(375, 375);
  image.SetPosition(i, 0, 1, 0);
}
```

You'll need to make sure that the `Image` object is copied (and not linked) into the spreadsheet, otherwise, you'll need to dispose them later, but it *should* be the case, taking the GC behaviour you are seeing.

PS: As I mentioned above, and as @ScottChamberlain noted in the comments, the image may be added as a reference (and not as a copy), so you'd dispose an image referenced in the collection. **if this is the case**, we can unlock the file by creating a copy (this should free the file), and then dispose the copy later after we're done with our package... something like:

```
var imageList = new List<Image>();
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
{
   /* ... */
         if (File.Exists(imagePath))
         {
            Image ImageToPutInReport;
            // Make a copy of the loaded image and dispose the original
            // so the file is freed
            using(var tempImage = Image.FromFile(imagePath))
               ImageToPutInReport = new Bitmap(tempImage);

            // Add to the list of images we'll dispose later 
            // after we're done
            imageList.Add(ImageToPutInReport);
            var image = ws2.Drawings.AddPicture(imagesLocations[i].Name, ImageToPutInReport);
            image.SetSize(375, 375);
            image.SetPosition(i, 0, 1, 0);
        }
   /* ... */
   package.SaveAs(fileInfo);
}
foreach(var img in imageList)
  img.Dispose();
imageList.Clear();
```

Comment: The problem with that is I think `ws2.Drawings.AddPicture` is keeping a reference to `ImageToPutInReport` so now you have a disposed image in a collection

Comment: @ScottChamberlain that's what I said about the image being copied and not referenced... I believe that should not be the case (since it seems by the code that `AddPicture` returns another `Image`, so I figured it'd be copied - **disclaimer:** I don't know the API and I'm basing on the code and the variable names, *which might not be a good idea*), but it definitely could

Comment: If disposing after adding works, probably they are the same. `Image.FromFile` more likely opens a stream like in the accepted answer (I haven't checked)